# Booting IDE as master, no boot, no operating sys (/w status need?)

Tags: boot, operating-systems, pata, status

Partitioning status (IDE must be booted in another PC:

[image: Partitioning status (IDE must be booted in another PC)]

Those are my partitionings.  I have 2 HDDs, 1 IDE and 1 SATA (which I'm running).  SATA (C:) gives status; (System, Boot, Page File, Active, Crashdump, Primary)

When I try booting (it is seen as master drive, which wasn't, but that I fixed with a jumper by Cable select), it simply says; 'No operating system found'

I earlier booted the (IDE) HDD via USB, I also installed via USB IDE/SATA converter.  The boot (which the OS is also on) must be partition called L:

[image: OS installed L:]

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to boot from L which is an ide drive? What are the 2 OS's on the IDE and the Sata? How did you install the OS on L (ide) drive? Was the sata drive connected when you installed the OS to the ide drive L? What motherboard do you have?, does it have both sata and ide connections on the motherboard? or is there an add in card for ide or sata?